# Batch MysqlDump error

Tags: batch-file, mysql

Bonjour,

I'm doing a save script of a database, with windows CLI.

When I use mysqlDump, I've got an error : "mysqldump: unknown option '-í'"

My file is created, but is empty.

Here is my code:

```html
@echo off
 
If "%1"=="" Goto BlocSi
 
Goto BlocSinon
 
Rem Bloc "Si"
 
:BlocSi
Echo Veuillez renseignez une base
Goto FinSi
 
Rem Bloc "Sinon"
 
:BlocSinon
 
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin/mysqldump ­­user=root %1 > base.sql
 
 :FinSi
```

On command line I type "save.bat twitter".

My database is "twitter", my user root, and there is no password.

Help me please :).

Comment: I would advise you to remove the `@echo off` to see what the command is; (does `%1` contain a `-i`?). You also could try with `mysqldump ­­--user=root -- %1` (see [what does the double dash mean](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash)).

Answer (score 0):

I think the user option is used incorrectly.

It should be --user=root, or -u root

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_user

Answer (score 0):

you are using username argument wrongly, so either your command should be-

```
mysqldump ­­--user=root %1 > base.sql

OR 

mysqldump ­­-u root %1 > base.sql

OR

mysqldump ­­-uroot %1 > base.sql
```